# How can I sort this data using Python?

Tags: python, sorting, split, alphabetical

I am writing a program that reads in a text file containing two columns.

It needs to sort the first column based on the last character in it and output to a new file. If the last characters in the first set is the same then it sorts by the first character. If the last and first character are the same, then it sorts by the middle character. For example, the data being read from the file would be:

```
ac  123 
aba 456 
abd 456 
bda 123 
baa 123
```

For the first row, `"a"` is the first character and `"c"` is the last character, there is no middle character.

The output should look like this:

```
aba 456 
baa 123 
bda 123 
ac  123 
abd 456
```

So far I have been able to read in the file and split it up, however I am stuck on figuring out how to sort it alphabetically. Can someone suggest what might help me?

This is my code so far:

```
f = open('example.txt','r')
new = []
for row in f.readlines():
     data = row.split()
     print(data)
```

The output looks like:

```
['ac', '123']
['aba', '456']
['abd', '456']
['bda', '123']
['baa', '123']
```

Am I going in the right direction?

I also was reading about something called `lambda` and I'm not sure if that would be useful or not because I have never used it in Python.

Comment: Have you considered [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)?

Comment: Will that allow me to sort it by the specific (third) character in the first set? I didn't think it would be that simple, unless I am just over thinking it.

Comment: What should happen if a string has no middle character and you need to use the middle character for a tie-breaker?

Comment: The string that has a middle character will take priority over the one that doesn't.

Comment: @Eric you will have to tell `sorted` how you want to sort, using e.g. the `lambda` you mention.

Comment: `lambda` is a way to define a simple function on the fly. It's handy when you just need a one-off key function or something like that -- it saves having to create one with `def`. It sounds like you're studying Python; you'll read about it in due course.

Comment: if you had all the sublists in one list, a lambda  to sort by the last char  would be `sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0][-1])`,`x[0][-1])` is the  the last char in your strings in each sublist and `l` would be your list.

Answer (score 3):

Read the data into a list, then sort with `key=keyfunc`. Pardon me not giving you a complete solution, but this smells like homework, so.

```
def keyfunc(s):
    firstword = s.split()[0]
    char1 = firstword[-1]
    char2 = firstword[0]
    char3 = firstword[1] if len(firstword) == 3 else ""
    return char1 + char2 + char3
```

Comment: I understand and I thank you. I was just looking for some help, not a complete solution. I will implement this and see where I can go from there.

Comment: Wish more people had that attitude :)

Comment: @TomZych Plzz tho it not hw, I just needs it really fast NOW!

Comment: Sadly, "LOL" is too short for a comment :)